# How to convert a set of Integers to an int[] array?

Tags: java, collections

I have no problems converting a `Set` of strings to a `String[]` array, but I'm having problems doing so with converting a `Set` of `Integer` to an `int[]` array.

How can I convert the `Integers` to its corresponding primitive?

I cannot seem to find any related questions. Any quick suggestions that can help?

Sometimes, autoboxing cannot be used, as in the case of arrays. I don't think an array of integers will automatically be converted to an array of ints.

Comment: Not possible with `toArray(T[])`. Just loop over it yourself and let autoboxing do its job.

Comment: Why do you want an `int`? Any specific reason that `Integer` is not ok?

Answer (score 16):

`string[]` doesn't exist, I guess you mean `String[]`.

For converting a `Set<Integer>` to `int[]` you'd have to iterate over the set manually.

Like this:

```
Set<Integer> set = ...;

int[] arr = new int[set.size()];

int index = 0;

for( Integer i : set ) {
  arr[index++] = i; //note the autounboxing here
}
```

Note that sets don't have any particular order, if the order is important, you'd need to use a  `SortedSet`.

Comment: yes lol. thats what i meant Thomas. sorry typo error. Thank you though.

Comment: For some reason its not allowing the type of element to be of Integer in the for each loop.

Comment: Then it's not a `Set<Integer>` but a `Set` or `Set<SomethingElse>`.

Answer (score 13):

This is why Guava has an [`Ints.toArray(Collection<Integer>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29) method, returning `int[]`.

Answer (score 12):

With java 8:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(); 
// TODO: Add implement for set

int[] array = set.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: This is a 7-year-old question and your answer does not seem to add anything not covered by the other answers. It is good to answer the questions you can, but maybe invest your time in more recent (preferably unanswered) questions. And if you add an answer to a question which already has answers, try to make sure that it cover points, the other answers do not.

Comment: It's the only one-line pure Java solution I've found. It definitely does add something not covered by the other answers. I see nothing wrong with providing new answers to old questions, especially since it helped me in this case.

Comment: You can do this for a shorter version: `set.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()`. Auto-unboxing will handle the conversion from `Integer` so you don't need `Integer::intValue`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that `Set<Integer>.toArray` converts to `Integer[]`, rather than `int[]`. So you have no simple way: you need to iterate through the set manually and add its elements to the int array. Converting an individual `Integer` to `int` is handled by autoboxing in Java 5 and above.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming auto unboxing!

```
Set<Integer> myIntegers; // your set
int[] ints = new int[myIntegers.size()];
int index = 0;
for(Integer i : myIntegers){
    ints[index++] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the

```
Integer.intValue();
```

function...

lemme know more specifics of what you need :)

Comment: Thanks Piyush. Ill have a go using this function.

Comment: balus got it right mate! Please accept the answer if u liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 5+ Autoboxing should take care of this...!

What error do you get?

edit: ok i see..

Like other said:

loop on your Set and just put the Integer inside the int[], autoboxing should convert it.